# Basic question about the definition of an integral on a measure space

Tags: measure-theory

Let $(X,\mathcal{B},\mu)$ be a measure space.

---

$\bf{\text{Definition:}}$  For a non-negative measurable function $f$ on $X$, $E\in \mathcal{B}$,

$$\int_{E}f d\mu := \text{inf}\int_{E}\varphi d\mu$$

where the infimum is taken over all simple functions $\varphi$ such that $0\leq \varphi \leq f$.

---

$\bf{\text{My question:}}$

When I am using the definition to prove something for such a function $f$, I want to take a sequence of simple functions $\varphi_{n}$ with $0\leq \varphi_{n}\leq f$ such that

$\int_{E}fd\mu = \lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\int_{E}\varphi_{n}d\mu$.

Is it possible to choose the sequence so that $\varphi_{n}(x)\to f(x)$ almost everywhere in $E$?

Comment: I think I may have figured out a way to answer this and it might be silly after all.

Comment: The dominated convergence theorem gives you exactly what you want, I think. Just *define* a suitable $\phi_n$. If they're all $\leq f$, $\phi_n \to f$ pointwise a.e., and $f$ is known to be integrable, by the dominated convergence theorem $\int f\,d\mu = \lim_{n\to\infty} \int \phi_n \,d\mu$

Comment: Btw, if you fingure out the answers yourself, why not post an answer to your own question?

Comment: You should replace your infimum by a supremum. If you take the inf over all $\phi \le f$, then you could just pick $\phi \equiv 0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Christopher A. Wong said, infimum should be supremum.

Yes, for example, $\varphi_n(x) = \min(2^n, 2^{-n} \lfloor 2^nf(x) \rfloor)$ is a sequence of simple functions that converges to $f$ at every point where $f(x)$ is finite. I used $2^n$ instead of $n$ to make the sequence increasing: $\varphi_n\le \varphi_{n+1}$.